# cmd.exe, append text on new line

Tags: windows, cmd, echo

I am trying to script appending a line to a file on multiple windows machines. the command `echo text >> file.txt` does not put the word `text` on a newline, but on the last line. I cannot seem to get \n or \r to work with echo on windows. help!

Comment: Please post an example of the code you are using. (And you are right, the `cmd.exe` `echo` command doesn't support escape sequences such as ```\n``` or ```\r```.)

Comment: Hi Bill - all of my code is in my post. just a simple `echo text >> file.txt`. It seems the only way to create a newline is to perform `echo. >> file.txt` before appending any text. would be nice to have it all on a single line :)

Comment: `>>` appends a line of text to a file, so I don't understand what you mean by "have it all on a single line." Maybe update your question with what you are expecting the file to look like?

Comment: It doesnt actually append a new line. It appends `text` to the last line in the doc, which is not always a new line. edit: ifit helps, i am on win10 1903

Comment: Well, it means "append to end of file". It doesn't analyze the file first. I still don't understand what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: Bill - I am looking for a one liner that will append text to a new line on a file.

Comment: That's precisely what `>>` does--it appends to the end of the file you specify. Please update your question with the unexpected results you are seeing. (I'm certain that the confusion is in your expectation of what `>>` does.)

Comment: `(echo/&echo text) >> file.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the last line in `file.txt` is not terminated by a line-break, so you can explicitly append such:

```cmd
rem // Append line-break plus text:
(echo/&echo text) >> file.txt
```

If `file.txt` may or may not be terminated by a line-break, you could use [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html):

```cmd
rem // Use `find` to force a final line-break, then append text and write to temporary file:
(find /V "" < file.txt & echo text) > file.txt.tmp
rem // Move temporary file onto original one:
move /Y file.txt.tmp file.txt
```

Note that `find` limits line lengths to 4095 characters or bytes.